# Who discovered the race in Ready Player One?

Tags: ready-player-one-2018

Who discovered the race in *Ready Player One*?

Was it just uncovered to make a start to the competition?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the stack! Take the [tour] when you have a chance, and visit the [help] for more guidance. Given that you included the [ready-player-one-2018] tag, I assume your question is about the film? If so, I've removed the other tag because I believe that's only for questions about the book.

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer at [Cinema Blend](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/2397142/6-questions-we-have-after-ready-player-one):

> At the beginning of Ready Player One, we learn that the first clue had already been deciphered and that it led to a race that, thus far, nobody had been able to complete. We're told that the identity of the person who solved it was unknown, but how can that be? The hunt had only been going on for five years. It's not like this stuff was lost to the ages. Was finding the race seriously worth zero points on the scoreboard? Did the avatar really decide to remain anonymous? There would have been no harm in making yourself known, at least inside the OASIS. Unless, of course, the puzzle had never actually been solved, and the race just opened on its own in order to get things moving, perhaps as a fail-safe instituted by James Halliday himself?